# Problem positioning customized X in a square in the same row

Tags: html, css

I have a simple square with a yes or no label:

```css
.yesNoSquare {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yesNoSquare-space {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="textCenter">
  <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
  <span class=" yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
  <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
  <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
</div>
```

I want to add an "X" inside the square to do something like this:

```css
.yesNoSquare {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yesNoSquare-space {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.yesNoSquare-cross {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  /*background-color: #FA6900;*/
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.yesNoSquare-cross:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 2px;
  content: "\2716";
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="textCenter">
  <div class="yesNoSquare-cross"></div>
  <span class=" yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
  <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
  <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
</div>
```

I used `div` instead of `span` because `span` did not display the square correctly, but when I try it, the square with the "X" does not display in the same line.

The desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block;` to `.yesNoSquare-cross`.

```css
.yesNoSquare {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yesNoSquare-space {
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.yesNoSquare-cross {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  /*background-color: #FA6900;*/
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;/*the new code*/
}

.yesNoSquare-cross:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 2px;
  content: "\2716";
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="textCenter">
  <div class="yesNoSquare-cross"></div>
  <span class=" yesNoSquare-space itemsTableHeader"> YES</span>
  <span class="yesNoSquare"></span>
  <span class="itemsTableHeader"> NO</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All that is needed are two standard checkboxes or two standard radio buttons. You can customize the look, once you decide which one you want.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check-yes">YES
<input type="checkbox" id="check-no">NO
<hr />
<input type="radio" id="radio-yes" name="yesno">YES
<input type="radio" id="radio-no" name="yesno">NO
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the semantically correct tags which are `<label>` and `<input type="checkbox">` or `<input type="radio">`. The example below shows how to customize labels, and checkbox/radio buttons. I used radio buttons since the boxes in OP were labeled "YES" and "NO". By assigning each radio button the same `name` value (in this case `name="yn"`), the radio button group become mutually exclusive, meaning that only one radio button can be checked while the other(s) must be unchecked.

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.25 'Segoe UI'
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: max-content;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

input {
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}

label {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0.45rem;
}

input.x {
  display: none;
}

label b {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 0.5px inset black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: scale(1.75);
}

input.x:checked+label b::before {
  content: '\2716';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -0.3rem;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 0.65rem;
  line-height: 0.5;
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Custom Radio Button Group</legend>
  <input id='yes' class='x' name='yn' type='radio'>
  <label for='yes'><b></b> YES</label>

  <input id='no' class='x' name='yn' type='radio'>
  <label for='no'><b></b> NO</label>
</fieldset>
```